# Can't read a file line-by-line in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've been trying to read a file line by line for my UNI project.
I am getting an error that I am not sure I understand. I would need your experiene to help me solve it out, please.

Some clarification for the code:
datas is a List, which has a custom class type which class has 3 properties: text1, text2, int1.
v is a simple object with the same custom class type as the datas List.
The data in the text file are in line-by-line, each line contains 1 value for the 3 properties like this: text1value;text2value;int1value.

```
if (File.Exists("example.txt"))
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("example.txt");
            while(!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] data = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
                v.text1 = data[0];
                v.text2 = data[1];
                v.int1 = Convert.ToInt32(data[2]);
                datas.Add(v);
            }
            sr.Close();
```

Thanks to you guys I have made improvements on my code and made it work!
Now I only have 1 functionality error which I do not understand on the code which is after the read in is completed. (so the code runs without error, crash, etc. - but gives the wrong result SOMETIMES!).

```
            int i = 0;
            int cnt = datas.Count;
            while (i < cnt)
            {
                if (datas[i].Text1 == tb_Text1.Text && datas[i].Text2 == tb_Text2.Text)
                {
                    // I do stuff here with the correct combination
                    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
             if(i==cnt)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The following combination is not in the txt file!");
                }
         }
```

So in the second part of the code, on the Windows Form, there are 2 textboxes: one is for the text1 property, the other is for the text2 property.

I would like it to work like it would in a username-password scenario.
If the user types a text1 and text2 value in the textboxes, and clicks on the button which is on the Form, and that specific text1 and text2 values are stored in the same line of the txt file which was read in in the first half of the code, it should ACCEPT that combination.

Now, my problem is, I have 2 lines of records in my txt file right now.
So that should mean that in my datas named List, there should be 2 "items".
The first line for example is this in the txt file: Example1;example123;1
And the second line is this: Example2;example234;1

Every time I write Example2 and example234 in the textboxes, it WORKS.
Every time I write Example1 and example123 in the textboxes, it DOESNT WORK and I get the MessageBox message.

Anyone have any idea where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why have a loop with `int j` and not use it?

Comment: Any particular reason to stream the file in? If not, you could always use `File.ReadAllLines`

Comment: @asawyer The reason I used StreamReader is because that is the only way our teacher showed us file reading.

Comment: @berkobienb I would gladly use the loop with j, but not sure what should I change to make it work?

Comment: When you call `ReadLine()` the stream advances to the next line, so you will not be able to read that line again.

Comment: @Noxter Ok, but your already using `System.IO.File.Exists` may as well throw `ReadAllLines` into the  mix. At that point it's just `var datas = File.ReadAllLines("example.txt").Select(l=>l.Split(';')).Select(s=>new V(){text1=s[0], text2=s[1], int1=int.Parse(s[2])});` for whatever type that `v` is, as it's not show in your code sample.

Comment: You may also have a big problem with that `v` - if it's a `class` at the end of your file read the `datas` collection may not contain the values you expect. `v`  should be a new instance per line instead of reusing a single instance's properties.

Comment: @Noxter Regarding your edit - this should be a new question. However, I strongly suspect that your seeing the behavior I talked about in my previous comment.

Comment: The way you have it setup now your adding a reference to a single instance to the collection multiple times, and mutating that instance per read line. Therefore since all index's into `datas` point to the same instance of `v` all you will see is whatever the value of the last read line was no matter what index or element of `datas` is examined.

Comment: First of all thanks for the feedback regarding the edit - I did not know this but I will keep in mind for the future. To the indexing part: since English is not my mother tongue, I am not 100% sure if I understand you correctly. So the problem is, that I put every line into the same "v" named object?So I should do v1, v2, etc?The problem with that is, that I do not know how many lines there will be. And I thought that when i type datas.Add(v), then the 3 parameters of v will be stored in the List datas as a single "item". And after it has been stored, I should be able to read in the next line.

Comment: @asawyer Since I am a beginner in C#, I actually do not know how to solve this issue right now. If the "v1, v2" is not the solution, then I think I misunderstood your comment. I thought, that the point of Lists is that they are like arrays, but dynamic in length.

Comment: @asawyer So, why does it matter, that I put every line into v before putting it into the List? Like what would I do if I would have 200 lines? It shouldn't be a problem to use the same v. V is like this: Classname v = new Classname(), and the class has the 3 properties. What should I do instead? :(

Comment: @Noxter Delete wherever you declare `v`. Then after the line `string[] data = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');` Add `var v = new Classname();` At that point each item added to `datas` will be it's own instance of the type with it's own separate values and it all should work as expect.

Comment: @asawyer Thank you very much. It works. Can I give you the solve of the issue somehow? Would you like to have it so you get some points or something? But you only wrote comments so I dont know if I can. You helped me a lot and now it works as intended! And I actually learned about a very important thing of C#, so thank you!

Comment: @Noxter Your very welcome. Sooner or later this sort of thing will become second nature, keep it up! Write up exactly what you did as an answer clearly defining why it change was made and accept it.

Comment: The "correct combination check" works fine in my test. Did you type extra spaces in the TextBox. Try to call `String.Trim()` to check it. Or, did you modify the txt file?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to do something along these lines? The ReadLine() will automatically move to the next row in the file.

```
if (File.Exists("example.txt"))
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("example.txt");
            while(!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] data = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
                v.text1 = data[0];
                v.text2 = data[1];
                v.int1 = Convert.ToInt32(data[2]);
                datas.Add(v);
            }
            sr.Close();
         }
```

To propose an additional improvement, use `using` to create the `StreamReader` and it will take care of the file handeling for you:

```
if (File.Exists("example.txt"))
    {
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("example.txt"))
        {
            while(!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] data = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
                v.text1 = data[0];
                v.text2 = data[1];
                v.int1 = Convert.ToInt32(data[2]);
                datas.Add(v);
            }
        }
     }
```

(And maybe include the case that the file does not exist as an error and catch it.)

Comment: Ha ha, we have the same answer.

Comment: @PaulSinnema Haha, nice one :P

Comment: @Marcus thank you! With this, I could manage to make my code work, but I got another problem (Edited my post with it). Do you have any idea about that as well? A comment or solution would be really appreciated! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Noxter, When asking questions you should only ask one question per post and not edit out any question as others might use your question to solve their problems. In this case, I can't see any obvious problem with your code, so I would recommend trying to debug by splitting the code into smaller parts so you can find where the problem is. For example, try to print what's in `data` to see if example1 actually is in there.

Comment: @Marcus Thank you for you feedback regarding the editing - I did not know this, but I will keep it in mind for the future to not make this mistake again! Thank you for the tip as well!

Answer (score 1):

Remove your loop:

```
for(int j=0; j<x; j++)
{
    sr.ReadLine();
}
```

I am assuming you are attempting to position to the correct line, but `StreamReader.ReadLine()` already advances the read position. You don't need the loop.

What is happening is that your loop is reading past the end of the file, so then the `ReadLine` in

```
string[] data = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
```

returns null, and so the `Split()` throws a null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is the while. The for() loop will just disrupt the flow. My guess is you think you have to read from the start every time you want to do a ReadLine(). But the stream will remember where you left off after the last ReadLine().

```
    if (File.Exists("example.txt"))
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("example.txt");
        while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string[] data = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');
            v.text1 = data[0];
            v.text2 = data[1];
            v.int1 = Convert.ToInt32(data[2]);
            datas.Add(v);
        }
        sr.Close();
     }
```

Comment: Fyi `StreamReader` should be disposed.

Comment: @PaulSinnema Thank you for your help! This fixed my code, but I got another problem (it is about functionality, so the code itself runs without error). Do you have any idea about that as well? Thank you!

Comment: What is your question? B.t.w. Mark my answer as the right one when think that is appropriate.